# How to update a one to many relationship MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

If i have a Person collection that has many addresses, how can I insert multiple addresses that belong to a person? I know how to do it if it were a one to one relationship where I would simply do something like:

```js
db.persons.update({_id: '12345'}, {$set: {'address': '12345 fake st'}})
```

However, that won't work for a one to many relationship since the person's address would get replaced every time someone adds an address to that person. Can someone help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a person to hold many addresses then you could make `address` an array and you could insert new addresses using the `push` operator.

```js
db.persons.update(
    { "_id": "12345" }, 
    { "$push": { "address": "12345 fake st"}}
);
```

Your schema would then look like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : "12345",
    "address" : [
        "12345 fake st",
        "6789 second st",
        ...
    ]
}
```

Of course you can make this as complex as required. So if you need to store extra information for each address, you can instead insert subdocuments into the `address` array.

```js
{
    "_id" : "12345",
    "address" : [
        {
            "number" : "6789",
            "street" : "second st",
            "primary" : false
        },
        {
            "number" : "12345",
            "street" : "fake st",
            "primary" : true
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

As noted in the comments, if you want to ensure that there are no duplicates in your array, you should use the `$addToSet` operator, which provides that functionality.

Comment: thanks - i was just doing some more research on this and is this any different or does it have any advantages over using the $addToSet operator?

Comment: The `$addToSet` operator ensures that there are no duplicates in the array. In your case, it would make sense to use `$addToSet`, unless you want duplicates. I have noted that in the answer to be clear.